# Creating a nested attributes form in show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am familiar with how to get a typical nested_attributes form working in Rails 4. However I'm attempting to create a form on a views/people/show.html.erb template that is just for one of the nested attributes on my Person model.

```
class Person
  has_many :histories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :histories
end

class History
  belongs_to :person
end
```

View

```
<% @person.histories.each do |history| %>
  <% if history.created_at != nil %>
    <p>Date: <%= history.created_at.strftime("%a, %b %e %Y") %></p>
    <p>Visit Summary: <%= history.visit_summary %></p>
  <% else %>
    <p>N/A</p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @person do |p| %>
  <%= p.fields_for :histories do |history| %>
    <%= history.label :visit_summary %>
    <%= history.text_area :visit_summary %>
  <% end %>
  <%= p.submit 'Create History Item' %>
<% end %>
```

I know I've made some egregious logic-in-the-view errors, but what I'm basically trying to accomplish with this form is when a person navigates to /persons/:id they see a summary of the person, including the histories associated with that person. They also have a form for JUST adding a single History item to the persons histories collection.

Right now, in order to get the form to show up in the view I have to edit my controller as such:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @person = Person.find(person_params)
    @person.histories.build
  end
end
```

However, calling that histories.build creates an object that ends up being shown in the list of history items in the view, even though it hasn't been persisted to the database yet, hence my logic for excluding history items whose created_at attribute is nil. Also, when I submit a history item and get redirected to /people/:id I am presented with two form fields; one to edit my previously created history item and one to create a new history item. I only want one empty form field present at any given time.

My questions are:

1.) How can I make a small, single attribute form for an association on my person model to be displayed in the show.html.erb template?

2.) Is using a nested_attributes form the way to go about it?

3.) Can online documentation be provided that shows how to create these kinds of small custom forms?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new History object that isn't yet associated to a person object and form that has the `visit_summary` input `post`ing to your `histories#create` route. within that route, create a new History with the input param, then assign the person to it, and save.
Essentially, just because you have a nested association, doesn't mean you can't just create a history object by itself.

in your person controller:

```
def show
  @person = Person.find(person_params)
  @history = History.new
end
```

your form

```
<%= form_for [@person, @history] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :visit_summary %>
  <%= f.text_area :visit_summary %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create History Item' %>
<% end %>
```

alternatively, you can use a hidden field tag if you dont want to use the `@person` in the `form_for` method:

```
<%= form_for @history do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:person_id, value: @person.id) %>
  <%= f.label :visit_summary %>
  <%= f.text_area :visit_summary %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create History Item' %>
<% end %>
```

your histories controller

```
def create
  history = History.new(history_params)
  history.person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
  history.save
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that I don't need to try to reinvent the wheel. I really should have thought about how the desired form functionality was just a basic post / comment style functionality.